# highlight all divs with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-animate

So I have a section with 15 team members (.member). If I hover over a member of the, let's say design team, every not design member will get a .3 opacity. What I have so far is this:

```
  // ENGINEERS
    $('.engineer').hover(function() {
        $('.member').not($('.engineer')).stop().animate({
            opacity: .3
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $('.member').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    }, 150);

  // DESIGNERS
    $('.designer').hover(function() {
        $('.member').not($('.designer')).stop().animate({
            opacity: .3
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $('.member').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    }, 150);

    // PRODUCT
    $('.product').hover(function() {
        $('.member').not($('.product')).stop().animate({
            opacity: .3
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $('.member').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    }, 150);
```

It works, but for every category you'll have to add a new function. This is probably a noob question, but can I unify those functions? I tried it with .each(), but I am stuck when it comes to selecting all the other members and fading them out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `this` like this:

```
$('.product , .designer , .engineer').hover(function() {
    $('.member').not($(this)).stop().animate({ 
        opacity: .3
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    $('.member').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
}, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple selectors like this [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('.engineer, .designer, .product').hover(function () {
    $('.member').not($(this)).stop().animate({
        opacity: .3
    }, 300);
}, function () {
    $('.member').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
}, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try  as

```
 $('.product , .designer , .engineer').on('hover', function() {
   $('.member').not($(this)).stop().animate({ 
    opacity: .3
   }, 300);
  }, function() {
    $('.member').stop().animate({
    opacity: 1
   });
}, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight redesign in the html can solve the problem

In the markup add a additional attribute `data-type` as shown below

```
<div class="member engineer" data-type="engineer">e4</div>
```

then

```
var members = $('.member').hover(function() {
    members.filter('[data-type="' + $(this).data('type') + '"]').stop().animate({
        opacity: .3
    }, 300);
}, function() {
    members.filter('[data-type="' + $(this).data('type') + '"]').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
}, 150);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JNEKm/)